# Some warnings being treated as errors

Tags: linux, compilation, driver

I was trying to compile a driver for a Wireless USB dongle on my Arch (kernel build 3.18.14-2), while I came across this error: `cc1: some warnings being treated as errors`. I have checked a few tips on how to remove that warning message, where people said it is needed to remove the `-Werror` in the Makefile. However, I have checked and there is no `-Werror` in that file. Any tips?